# Convert columns to xml collection with attributes

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I would like to have a row for each row in the table, but transform the columns to an xml collection as efficiently as possible.  In the example below it is a flattened table - but in the real world the columns would require many joins to get - resulting in many reads.

For example:

```
declare @tbl table (
 Id int identity (1, 1) primary key
,PolicyNumber   varchar(100) not null
,InsuredName    varchar(100) not null
,EffectiveDate  datetime2 not null
,Premium        numeric(22, 7)
)

insert into @tbl (PolicyNumber, InsuredName, EffectiveDate, Premium)
values ('2017A-ALKJ02', 'Insured Number 1', '2017-01-01', 1000)
  ,('2017A-BSDSDFWEF2', 'Insured Number 2', '2017-06-01', 2000)

select Id
  ,(select [@name] = 'PolicyNumber', [@type] = 'string', [text()] = PolicyNumber from @tbl [inner] where [inner].Id = [outer].Id for xml path ('dt'))
  ,(select [@name] = 'InsuredName', [@type] = 'string', [text()] = [inner].InsuredName from @tbl [inner] where [inner].Id = [outer].Id for xml path ('dt'))
  ,(select [@name] = 'EffectiveDate', [@type] = 'datetime', [text()] = [inner].EffectiveDate from @tbl [inner] where [inner].Id = [outer].Id for xml path ('dt'))
  ,(select [@name] = 'Premium', [@type] = 'numeric', [text()] = [inner].Premium from @tbl [inner] where [inner].Id = [outer].Id for xml path ('dt'))
from @tbl [outer]
```

Yields the individual columns in their own xml element, but I am after each row to have it's primary key and the structure:

```
<dts>
  <dt name="PolicyNumber" type="string">2017A-ALKJ02</dt>
  <dt name="InsuredName" type="string">Insured Number 1</dt>
  <dt name="EffectiveDate" type="datetime">2017-01-01T00:00:00</dt>
  <dt name="Premium" type="numeric">1000.0000000</dt>
</dts>
```

I understand this can be achieved with many sub-queries, but does anyone know of an easy way to have a single query that is smart enough to have the PK and all the individual columns transformed into an element in the dts collection?

Comment: Add `for xml path ('dts')` to the outer query. And add the `TYPE` directive to the subqueries (e.g. `for xml path ('dt'), type`). Oh, and remove the joins... e.g. your entire "subquery" should just be like `(select [@name] = 'PolicyNumber', [@type] = 'string', [text()] = PolicyNumber for xml path ('dt'), type)`

Comment: @ZLK Good suggestion! But you can do this without any subquery too. This is especially useful if there are namespaces involved, which would be repeated in each sub-query otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know all metadata (column name and type) in advance this can be done very simply like here:

```
declare @tbl table (
 Id int identity (1, 1) primary key
,PolicyNumber   varchar(100) not null
,InsuredName    varchar(100) not null
,EffectiveDate  datetime2 not null
,Premium        numeric(22, 7)
);

insert into @tbl (PolicyNumber, InsuredName, EffectiveDate, Premium)
values ('2017A-ALKJ02', 'Insured Number 1', '2017-01-01', 1000)
  ,('2017A-BSDSDFWEF2', 'Insured Number 2', '2017-06-01', 2000);

SELECT 'PolicyNumber' AS [dt/@name]
      ,'string' AS [dt/@type]
      ,PolicyNumber AS [dt]
      ,''
      ,'InsuredName' AS [dt/@name]
      ,'string' AS [dt/@type]
      ,InsuredName AS [dt]
      ,''
      ,'EffectiveDate' AS [dt/@name]
      ,'datetime' AS [dt/@type]
      ,EffectiveDate AS [dt]
      ,''
      ,'Premium' AS [dt/@name]
      ,'numeric' AS [dt/@type]
      ,Premium AS [dt]
FROM @tbl 
FOR XML PATH('dts'),ROOT('root')
```

The result

```
<root>
  <dts>
    <dt name="PolicyNumber" type="string">2017A-ALKJ02</dt>
    <dt name="InsuredName" type="string">Insured Number 1</dt>
    <dt name="EffectiveDate" type="datetime">2017-01-01T00:00:00</dt>
    <dt name="Premium" type="numeric">1000.0000000</dt>
  </dts>
  <dts>
    <dt name="PolicyNumber" type="string">2017A-BSDSDFWEF2</dt>
    <dt name="InsuredName" type="string">Insured Number 2</dt>
    <dt name="EffectiveDate" type="datetime">2017-06-01T00:00:00</dt>
    <dt name="Premium" type="numeric">2000.0000000</dt>
  </dts>
</root>
```

The trick is the nameless empty "column" between the `<dt>` elements. The engine is told: Look, there's a new element, close the one before and start a new one!

Otherwise you'd get an error...

### UPDATE: generic approach

This will extract all meta data and construct the same statement as above, which is executed with `EXEC`:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpTbl (
 Id int identity (1, 1) primary key
,PolicyNumber   varchar(100) not null
,InsuredName    varchar(100) not null
,EffectiveDate  datetime2 not null
,Premium        numeric(22, 7)
);

insert into tmpTbl (PolicyNumber, InsuredName, EffectiveDate, Premium)
values ('2017A-ALKJ02', 'Insured Number 1', '2017-01-01', 1000)
  ,('2017A-BSDSDFWEF2', 'Insured Number 2', '2017-06-01', 2000);

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT ' +
STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',''' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ''' AS [dt/@name]' +
          ',''' + c.DATA_TYPE + ''' AS [dt/@type]' +
          ',' + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) + ' AS [dt]' + 
          ',''''' 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c WHERE TABLE_NAME='tmpTbl' 
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'') + 
'FROM tmpTbl FOR XML PATH(''dts''),ROOT(''root'')';
EXEC( @cmd);
GO
--cleanup (careful with real data)
--DROP TABLE tmpTbl;
```

If you need for example "string" instead of "varchar" you'd need a mapping table or a `CASE` expression.

Comment: The blank column was the missing piece of the puzzle - also the generic approach answered my next question.  I wasn't clear in my question that I needed an xml for each row (every answer didn't include it).  Instead of doing everything in one large query breaking into a temp table is the preferred approach.  See below for my final solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solve using different techniques. Here is one of them using `UNPIVOT` to generate the type column:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT [id]
          ,[column]
          ,[value]
          ,CASE [column]
                WHEN 'PolicyNumber' THEN 'string'
                WHEN 'InsuredName' THEN 'string'
                WHEN 'EffectiveDate' THEN 'datetime'
                WHEN 'Premium' THEN 'numeric'
           END AS [type]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT Id
              ,PolicyNumber
              ,InsuredName
              ,CAST(EffectiveDate AS VARCHAR(100)) AS EffectiveDate 
              ,CAST(Premium AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Premium
        FROM @tbl
    ) DS
    UNPIVOT
    (
        [value] FOR [column] IN ([PolicyNumber], [InsuredName], [EffectiveDate], [Premium])
    ) UNPVT
)
SELECT DISTINCT [id]
               ,[Info]
FROM @tbl DS
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT [column]  "@name"
          ,[type] "@type"
          ,CASE WHEN [column] = 'EffectiveDate' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CAST([value] AS DATETIME2), 126) ELSE [value] END "text()"
    FROM DataSource Info
    WHERE DS.[Id] = Info.[Id]
    FOR XML PATH('dt'), ROOT('dts')
) DSInfo (Info);
```

It will give you XML like this for each row:

```
<dts>
    <dt name="PolicyNumber" type="string">2017A-ALKJ02</dt>
    <dt name="InsuredName" type="string">Insured Number 1</dt>
    <dt name="EffectiveDate" type="datetime">2017-01-01T00:00:00</dt>
    <dt name="Premium" type="numeric">1000.0000000</dt>
</dts>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no convenient way to produce this kind of output in SQL Server. One possible solution might be a FLWOR transformation, but I suspect it will be quite convoluted, indeed.

The other is by using `UNPIVOT`, as in the example below, though it is far from being easily expandable:

```
select (
    select upt.ColumnName as [@name],
        isnull(dt.ColumnType, 'string') as [@type],
        upt.ColumnValue as [text()]
    from (
        select t.Id, t.PolicyNumber, t.InsuredName,
            convert(varchar(100), t.EffectiveDate, 126) as [EffectiveDate],
            cast(t.Premium as varchar(100)) as [Premium]
        from @tbl t
    ) sq
    unpivot (
        ColumnValue for ColumnName in (
            sq.PolicyNumber, sq.InsuredName, sq.EffectiveDate, sq.Premium
        )
    ) upt
        left join (values
            ('EffectiveDate', 'datetime'),
            ('Premium', 'numeric')
        ) dt (ColumnName, ColumnType) on upt.ColumnName = dt.ColumnName
    where upt.Id = t.Id
    for xml path('dt'), type
    )
from @tbl t
for xml path('dts'), type;
```

First, you need to transpose column values into rows, so that your relational output will start resembling your required XML. In order to fit all your columns into the same `ColumnValue`, you have to cast them to the same data type.

Second, you have to provide the data for your `type` attribute. In the example above, I used an inline table constructor, because there is no way you can get data types from TV columns on the fly. If your actual data resides in a static table, you can try to join it with system metadata objects, such as `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. Although for your required values you will probably need an additional mapping table, as well (in order to substitute `varchar` with `string`, for example).

Last, in order to get a single `/dts` element for every original table row, I join the unpivotted data with the table again. This allows to generate the required nesting of XML elements, because `root()` clause is unsuitable for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions!  I decided flattening the query into a temp table is the best approach, then using the generic approach above plus the blank column trick satisfies the need.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tmp') is not null
    drop table #tmp

create table #tmp (
     Id int identity (1, 1) primary key
    ,PolicyNumber   varchar(100) not null
    ,InsuredName    varchar(100) not null
    ,EffectiveDate  datetime2 not null
    ,Premium        numeric(22, 7)
);

insert into #tmp (PolicyNumber, InsuredName, EffectiveDate, Premium)
values ('2017A-ALKJ02', 'Insured Number 1', '2017-01-01', 1000)
  ,('2017A-BSDSDFWEF2', 'Insured Number 2', '2017-06-01', 2000);

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)='
select [outer].Id
      ,convert(xml, (SELECT ' +
            STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ',[dt/@n] = ''' + c.name + '''' +
                      ',[dt/@t] = ''' + case when t.name = 'bit' then 'b'
                                             when t.name in ('date', 'smalldatetime', 'datetime2', 'datetime', 'datetimeoffset') then 'd'
                                             when t.name = 'bigint' then 'g'
                                             when t.name in ('tinyint', 'smallint', 'int', 'time', 'timestamp') then 'i'
                                             when t.name in ('real', 'smallmoney', 'money', 'float', 'decimal', 'numeric') then 'n'
                                             else 's'
                                        end + '''' +
                      ',[dt] = ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) +  
                      ',''''' 
                FROM tempdb.sys.columns c 
                  inner join sys.types t on c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
                where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#tmp')
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'') + '
        FROM #tmp [inner]
        where [inner].Id = [outer].id
        for xml path (''dts'')))
from #tmp [outer]'

EXEC( @cmd);
```